# Nickel Spoon Conundrum - Thought Experiment & Question

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, magnetic-fields, temperature

Scenario:
The Curie temperature of pure nickel is 354 degrees Celcius.
A teaspoon made of pure nickel sits on a flat surface adjacent to a permanent magnet.
The ambient temperature of the room they are in is 380 degrees Celcius.
The magnet and the spoon are both at the ambient temperature of the room.
Because the spoon is significantly warmer than its Curie temperature, it is insufficiently attracted to the permanent magnet to cause it to 'fly' towards the magnet.
The temperature of the room is then gradually lowered to 20 degrees Celcius.
During this reduction in temperature the B field within the spoon assumes enough order to cause it to be attracted with sufficient force to overcome its inertia and 'fly' to the permanent magnet.
Question:
Where has the kinetic energy in the motion of the spoon to the magnet come from - e.g. will the spoon be fractionally cooler when it arrives at the magnet (i.e. has it 'paid' for its kinetic 'journey' to the magnet in heat energy)?
This has been disturbing me lately and I would appreciate your intelligence in helping me with it - thanks for your time, I hope you find it as interesting as I do!

Comment: Doesn't the energy come from the potential energy of magnetic attraction?

Answer (score 1):

Below the curie temperature, the magnetic monopoles begin aligning themselves with the external magnetic field. Without very rigorous mathematics, one can guess that the least energy configuration of the spoon-magnet system is reached when they have touched (otherwise the spoon would've come to rest at some other point and we see that it does not). So the question remains, how is this minimal energy config reaches from the initial state? The spoon starts moving. This changes the flux through it, producing eddy currents on its surface which oppose the motion towards the magnet. Field energy is expended to overcome this opposing factor and provide kinetic energy as well to the magnet. This expenditure of energy reduces the field energy to a minimum at the magnet.

This is my personal view. Any incorrect logic is welcome to be pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

The cooled spoon becomes ferromagnetic (according to a (Tc-T) power law)
and then is attracted to the magnet which polarizes it more fully.  That
polarization lowers the thermodynamic degrees of freedom inside the solid
material, which lowers the heat capacity, so the spoon temperature rises
as it approaches the magnet, but not its stored heat (this  is
an adiabatic process).   The stored magnetic energy around the
permanent magnet is reduced (that's where the kinetic energy comes from).

The spoon is magnetized, and the external field of that
magnet partly cancels the permanent magnet's far field, reducing
the stored field energy in exchange for its kinetic work.

Comment: @Lelouch also. <br>Thank you for taking the time to reply. <br>As we can probably agree the reduction of heat in this fictitious room is a 'catalyst' to the process. But what if the process were repeated many times (similarly to Teslas 1889 patented thermo-magnetic motor - https://teslauniverse.com/nikola-tesla/patents/us-patent-396121-thermo-magnetic-motor)? <br>Can you elaborate on the mechanisms by which the stored field energy of the permanent magnet is replenished? <br>Thank you.